# Calibrate camera in OpenCV using markers

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV in Python and I want to be able to track the location of a LED in a field (x,y). I have a camera that is on a pole near the corner of the field which is connected to a computer and takes picture.

I have 4 markers which marks the edges of the field and I know their actual location in meters.

I've tried using the calibrate camera method but couldn't understand how I can apply them when I only have 4 markers which are given as points (and not circles or things like that).

Thanks in advance.